Identify and include only those records that fulfill all criteria
I need help with a problem involving training sessions and employees who attend them.
My client has training sessions, in multiple different areas, three times a year - Fall, Winter and Spring, for its employees. People can choose to attend multiple trainings during the same offer period. So for example, out of 4/5 different training areas offered in Fall, people can choose any or all to attend.
Once they have been selected to attend, they can withdraw at any point in time, before the start of that training. They can withdraw from one or all. Also, they can attend and finish in only one training for any given session.
I need to identify the employees, in each session, who have been selected to attend at least one training but didn't finish and withdrew from all the trainings they applied to (#4 in Fall and #1 in Winter).
Also, need to identify and seperately flag cases where employees did not get selected in all but just one or two trainings and later withdrew from those trainings. (#3 in Fall and #4 in Winter).
Data Sample
I would be extremely grateful if someone could please help, this is beyond my prowess to run general queries.

To identify employees, in each session, who were selected to attend at least one training but didn't finish and withdrew from all the trainings they applied to:
SELECT
  employee_nbr,
  session
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      emloyee_nbr,
      session,
      SUM(CASE WHEN action_1 = 'Applied' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS applied_count,
      SUM(CASE WHEN action_2 = 'Selected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS selected_count,
      SUM(CASE WHEN action_3 = 'Withdrew' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS withdrew_count,
      SUM(CASE WHEN action_4 = 'Finished' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS finished_count
    FROM
      data
    GROUP BY
      employee_nbr,
      session
  )
WHERE
  selected_count >= 1
  AND finished_count = 0
  AND withdrew_count = applied_count

To identify and seperately flag cases where employees did not get selected in all but just one or two trainings and later withdrew from those trainings.
SELECT
  employee_nbr,
  session
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      employee_nbr,
      session,
      SUM(CASE WHEN action_2 = 'Selected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS selected_count,
      SUM(CASE WHEN action_2 = 'Not selected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_selected_count,
      SUM(CASE WHEN action_3 = 'Withdrew' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS withdrew_count,
    FROM
      data
    GROUP BY
      employee_nbr,
      session
  )
WHERE
  selected_count BETWEEN 1 AND 2
  AND not_selected_count >= 1
  AND withdrew_count = selected_count

